# How to Convert html + CSS page to pdf using Javascript, php etc?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

But please remember **i need a free library** which does not disturb css of my webpage and easily convert some part of my webpage. i used Jspdf but it disturbs my webpage's css.

Comment: **That's why** this is going to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

**Add fpdf file**

```
    <?php
require('fpdf.php');
           $pdf=new FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
            $pdf->Ln();
            $pdf->Ln();
            $pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(25,7,"Name",1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,7,"address",1);

            $pdf->Ln();
            $pdf->Cell(450,7,
        $pdf->Ln();
    ?>
```

**Here is the php code**

```
<?php
$name='your name';
$address='ypur address';
  $pdf->Cell(25,7,$studid,1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,7,$name,1);
            $pdf->Cell(40,7,$address,1);


            $pdf->Ln(); 
        }
$pdf->Output();
```

you download fpdf file to this link [enter link description here](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP,
>   that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands
>   for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit
>   your needs.

Quote obtained from their website: http://www.fpdf.org/