# Convert a long HTML page to PDF persisting CSS

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I have tried `JSPDF` and `HTML2Canvas` for this. While the HTML is rendered successfully, its CSS is entirely messed up. I also read somewhere that `html2canvas` doesn't work with long pages.

Can anyone provide me a simple Javascript code that takes DOM element and generates its PDF and also maintains its CSS? I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204254/how-to-convert-html-css-page-to-pdf-using-javascript-php-etc

Comment: that question is related to PHP. My app is made of AngularJS and Python

Comment: Check your tags in that case.

Comment: I use http://pdfmake.org/